# How to Save file names and their directories path in a text file using Python

Tags: python, string-comparison, file-comparison

I am trying to find a string that is contained in files under a directory. Then make it to store it's file names and directories under a new text file or something. 
I got upto where it is going through a directory and finding a string, then printing a result. But not sure of the next step.

Please help, I'm completely new to coding and python.

```
import glob, os



#Open a source as a file and assign it as source
source = open('target.txt').read()
filedirectories = []

#locating the source file and printing the directories.
os.chdir("/Users/a1003584/desktop")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=True):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
        if source in open(os.path.join(root, name)).read():
            print 'treasure found.'
```

Comment: You might find the [python tutor list](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/tutor) more appropriate for questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do a string comparison if your looking for a dictionary. Instead use the json module. Like this.

```
import json
import os

filesFound = []

def searchDir(dirName):
    for name in os.listdir(dirName):
        # If it is a file.
        if os.isfile(dirName+name):
            try:
                fileCon = json.load(dirName+name)
            except:
                print("None json file.")
            if "KeySearchedFor" in fileCon:
                filesFound.append(dirName+name)
        # If it is a directory.
        else:
            searchDir(dirName+name+'/')

# Change this to the directory your looking in. 
searchDir("~/Desktop")
open("~/Desktop/OutFile.txt",'w').write(filesFound)
```

Comment: What exactly is the difference, if were to use the json module?

Answer (score 0):

This should write the output to a csv file

```
import csv
import os

with open('target.txt') as infile: source = infile.read()

with open("output.csv", 'w') as fout:
    outfile = csv.writer(fout)
    outfile.writerow("Directory FileName FilePath".split())
    for root, dirnames, fnames in os.walk("/Users/a1003584/desktop", topdown=True):
        for fname in fnames:
            with open(os.path.join(root, fname)) as infile:
                if source not in infile.read(): continue
            outfile.writerow(root, fname, os.path.join(root, fname))
```